# Best way/practices to generate multiple result sets in stored procedure to different tabs in Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm looking to call a stored procedure on SQL Server via Excel. The reason I'm using Excel is because there are values being input by users which get passed in as parameters to the stored procedure and executed to return the resulting datasets in a new data tab. However, the stored procedure has about 6-7 select statements responsible for generating 6-7 result sets. Aside from creating separate stored procedures for each result set, which isn't feasible as its timely and the result sets build upon each other, what is the best way to handle this or solution to look into? Is it something I need to build into the logic of the stored procedure or something I can configure in Excel?

My stored procedure would look something like this to give you an idea

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT TOP 10 PersonType,NameStyle,Title 
  FROM [AdventureWorks2016CTP3].[Person].[Person]

SELECT  TOP 10 PersonType,Firstname,Lastname
  FROM [AdventureWorks2016CTP3].[Person].[Person_json]

SELECT ****
.
.
.
SELECT ****
END
GO
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Understood - I actually just used it for demonstration purposes but thanks for the helpful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the stored procedure give same column names to all the select statements and use `UNION` between them and then have an additional column to each select statement to identify which table the data is coming from, ideally use table name.

Then call the stored procedure into a main tab once and then reference that data into other tabs and filter them.

Comment: That works when each table output has the same number of columns but that is not the case across all the resulting datasets for me

Comment: In that case add a new columns with nulls to the select statements with fewer rows. eg:       `SELECT GETDATE() AS [Today] , NULL AS [Yesterday]  Union ALL  SELECT GETDATE() AS [Today] , GETDATE()-1 AS [Yesterday] from Table1`